# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous - when checking if a dataframe value is equal to a string

Tags: python, pandas

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
if products.code == 'attendance':
    print('Attendance Product Detected')
else:
    print('Attendance Not Detected')

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

However, when I type this in the console, it works fine:

```
products.code == 'attendance'
Out: 
0    True
Name: code, dtype: bool
```

How can I fix this, so the if and else functions work?

Comment: what are products and codes?are they class and the attributes?

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamShaswat for replying so quickly. Ayushgupta answered the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using .item()
and moreover try:

```
if "attendence"==products.code.item():
    print('Attendance Product Detected')
else:
    print('Attendance Not Detected')
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another way, but I don't know if it will work.
I see your products.code == 'attendance' result like a DataFrame.

```
if (products.code != 'attendance').empty:
    print('Attendance Product Detected')
else:
    print('Attendance Not Detected')
```

Comment: Please show your data under your question, maybe somebody could help you. It is a bit hard to imagine your data.